# dplyr fails to count substring in vector

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, plyr, grepl

I need to count recursively how many times a substring `x` appears in a vector of strings `data$y`

```
data <- data.frame(x=c("aa","bb","cc"),y=c("a & aa & aaa","b","aa"))

desiderata <- data %>%
  group_by(x) %>%
  summarise(n=sum(grepl(x,y)))

desiderata <- data.frame(x=c("aa","bb","cc"),n=c(3,0,0))
```

Comment: Are you sure it is 3 for the first record? I think it should be 2?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly it should be 2 for the 1st record. Here is the solution:

```
library(stringr)

data %>%
  group_by(x) %>%
  summarise(n = str_count(y, x))
```

Output:

```
  x         n
  <chr> <int>
1 aa        2
2 bb        0
3 cc        0
```

Regard the code - I don't think you need `group_by` and `summarise` - `mutate` would work just fine and you have full column for reference:

```
data %>%
  mutate(n = str_count(y, x))
```

Output:

```
   x            y n
1 aa a & aa & aaa 2
2 bb            b 0
3 cc           aa 0
```